# Generalized Euler Lagrange Equation with Integral of Action over a Compact Domain

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

An action integral
$$
S = \int_{\Omega}L(x_1,...,x_n,f,D_{x_1}f, ...,D_{x_n}f) dx_1\cdots dx_n,
$$
can be minimized over a compact set $\Omega$ via the multi-dimensional generalization of [Euler-Lagrange equation in the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_several_variables_with_single_derivative)
$$
\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial D_{x_i}f} = 0
$$
with $D_{x_i}f := \partial f/\partial x_i$, $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, and Lagrangian $L(x_1,...,x_n,f,D_{x_1}f, ...,D_{x_n}f)$.

I still couldn't figure out the derivation/proof of this multi-d extension. First of all, could someone point me to a nice derivation/proof of this extended case?

Having said that, I am particularly wondering how we could adopt this equation for arbitrary domains beyond product topology of intervals (i.e., $\Omega = I_1 \times I_2 \times \cdots \times I_n$ for closed intervals $I_i \in \mathbb{R}$). For example, when the domain is a closed n-ball $\Omega = B^n$. Do the same equations hold for any sufficient set of boundary conditions defined on the boundary of the ball $\partial \Omega = S^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you wrote is the generalization of the usual Euler-Lagrange equation from classical mechanics to *classical field theory*. You can find the derivation of this in a lot of places, just try searching for the "classical field theory version" of the Euler-Lagrange equations. For instance, you can look at Section 5.3 of Nastase's *Classical field theory*.

Also, there's no reason that these equations can only apply to products of intervals; the derivation doesn't assume anything like $\Omega = I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$. Indeed, these equations hold for any compact manifold $\Omega$ with boundary (for instance, $\Omega = \mathsf{B}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$), as long as you place appropriate boundary conditions on the fields (i.e., the functions $f$) that you're considering. This is because the derivation involves some kind of "integration by parts" that introduces a boundary term, which you'd like to make zero in order to obtain the equations above.

**Edit.** To be clear, maybe you're under the impression that we can only work with products $\Omega = I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$ since for the $1$-dimensional Euler-Lagrange equations (i.e. where we replace $x_1,\dots,x_n$ by $t$), we work with a single interval $\Omega = I$. But this is just because any compact $1$-dimensional manifold (connected, with nonempty boundary) has to be (diffeomorphic to) a closed interval! However, in dimensions $n > 1$, there are way more compact manifolds (with boundary) than just products of intervals.

Comment: Awesome. I was exactly under that impression since I hadn't been acquainted with its 'classical field theory version' before. My uneducated guess was exactly along the same lines with your response. Thank you much!

Comment: No problem! Yes, the idea of classical field theory is that you study "fields" $f$ which aren't "local," in the sense that they have a value $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in X$ at all points of your spacetime $\Omega$, where the elements of $X$ can be numbers, vectors, or whatever else. When $n=1$, if you think of your spacetime $\Omega =\mathbb{R}$ as just time, then you have classical mechanics – a "field" here is just a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$, giving you a value $f(t)\in X$ for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$. You can think of $f(t)$ as the position, at time $t$, of a particle moving through the space $X$.